# Pygame: How would I go about setting a text object, BUT the text is meant to keep changing?

Tags: python, text, pygame

I am creating a copy of the game Pig. I have got a text based version of the game working. I am just updating it to pygame, adding graphics and sounds.

I will eventually add in mouse toggles, but for now I am trying to update a score.

I have display a 'player1 score', 'player2 score' out. I am trying to see how will it work to display text that is not constant.

i got

**`player1_text = font.render('player1 score', True,(0,0,0))`**

same for player2

I am assuming maybe that the first parameter -->'player1 score'
I can pass a variable and if I update the variable. When i call `pygame.update()` it should work as I think it should.

Just want some conformation or a tip on actually doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track!

Use a variable.

Comment: Well i tried directly putting in a variable of the number, but it wont accept int. Only surface type. So i am puzzles as to how to pass a surface variable that changes

Comment: Ok never. I was able to found a tutorial from youtube that had someone implement putting in a score system. If anyone else interested >> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsZtosVMUGg

Answer (score 2):

Pygame Font objects are not meant to be updated and changed constantly.  You will need to call render(text) each time your text changes.  Render() will return a new surface, so you will need to blit that to your screen to make the change.